# proc ttest class, default group issue

Tags: class, sas, t-test

I would like to compare mean values of two groups using `proc ttest`, and I successfully did it as below.

```
proc ttest;
class group;
var score;
run;
```

But, this code just assumes observations with `group = 0` as the default group. So, the `t-statistics` is calculated based on `Mean` (score of obs with group= 0) minus Mean (score of obs with group= 1). But, I would like to have it the other way around.

It would just change the sign of `t-statistics`, but it's just what I wanted to do.

Is there an option to do so by simply adding an option?

I know I could have done it if I have made another dummy variable which is exactly the opposite of my group variable. But, I don't want to create more dummy variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER=DATA` will tell SAS to order the class variable based on when it encounters the values.  So if the `1` values are earlier than the `0` values, it will be first in the comparison.

For example:

```
data for_ttest;
  call streaminit(7);
  do group = 0 to 1;
    do _n_ = 1 to 50;
      score = rand('NORMAL',1,0.5)+group;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

proc sort data=for_ttest;
  by descending group;
run;

proc ttest data=for_ttest order=data;
  class group;
  var score;
run;
```

Without `ORDER=DATA`, it behaves as you saw, but with it, 1 is the first group.

You could also combine `ORDER=FORMATTED` with a format.

```
proc format;
  value groupf
  1="Group 1 (Value=1)"
  0="Group 2 (Value=0)"
  ;
quit;
proc ttest data=for_ttest order=formatted;
  class group;
  format group groupf.;
  var score;
run;
```

The labels in the `PROC FORMAT` are irrelevant, other than that they must be alphabetically sorted.  Unfortunately the `PRELOADFMT` option is not available in `PROC TTEST`, so you can't use the `NOTSORTED` trick in `PROC FORMAT` to allow this to work even with the original values (though you can use non-printing characters to mess with sort order if you *really* want to).